# Style visible in the Chrome Dev Tools but not applied on the screen

Tags: css, angular, svg, css-selectors

I've got a Angular Component that displays a svg (as template).

```
export class MirraLeftComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.green-status') ok = false;

  constructor() {
    of(null)
      .pipe(delay(1000))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.ok = true;
      });
  }
}
```

In the css, there is a this following rule :

```
.green-status [appToolBackground] {
  fill: chartreuse;
}
```

What I don't get, is why this style, while visible in the Chrome Dev Tools, is not applied on the screen.

[image]

This problem does not happen if I use a rule based on a class, not an attribute like this one:

```
.green-status .tool {
  fill: chartreuse;
}
```

Any idea why Chrome behaves like that with the attribute selector ?

Demo:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tqnfqt?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: In my usecase I need the classes to be dynamic. I just narrowed down the example to explain the problem here !

Comment: Seems like a Chrome bug, no? I.e. it displays correctly on Firefox doesn't it. If so report it to Chrome's bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the fill argument in the svg tag like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="chartreuse" width="97.345" height="90.739" viewBox="0 0 97.345 90.739">
```

Test

It works for me.

Comment: I looking for a solution that work with css, this is a narrowed down example here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently chrome can't select component elements via attribute selector – least if the attribute is custom/non-standard like "appToolBackground":

Selecting a "well-known" attribute will work.

```
.green-status path[transform] {
  fill: blue;
}

.green-status path[open] {
  fill: purple;
}
```

... rather hacky.

As a workaround you could apply an additional class to the path element (and toggle it if needed for different states)

```
.green-status .appToolBackground {
  fill: chartreuse;
}
```